# Hundreds of failing unit tests

Tags: c#, c++, unit-testing

I have inherited a very old (first commits are in 1999) code base and have found 500 of the 2000 or so unit tests to be failing. My question is, should I go through each test manually and check if it is still relevant or should I start over?

Comment: The very definition of a "Too broad" question.

Comment: Do you have some advice on how to narrow my question down?

Comment: How could anybody answer this question without any context information? IMO all of your suggestions could apply.

Comment: Go back to the requirements/spec and quantify which test should be failing because the code base has bugs.

Comment: You should first figure out *why* they're failing and whether they should. Why are you assuming that the tests are at fault and not the code they're testing?

Comment: My apologies I should have been clearer. The tests are old and haven't been updated as the code changed through the years, the code however has been through rigorous QA testing many times a year for many years. As there are a large amount I thought id seek advice before trying to get in there and look at each one, it may be prudent to start over

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nobody here can answer this as such, but you have to ask for each test:

1. Does this test still make sense? If not, remove it.
2. Is the test testing something that should work? Do something to fix it up.
3. Is the test conceptually useful, but what it tests has changed so it is now failing? Rewrite it so that it works in its new way.
4. How much effort to fix vs. value is the test? If it's a lot of effort, and low value, maybe remove it...

We can't really say whether you should do one thing or another.

It's probably worth just LOOKING at the tests, and especially looking at the effort of fixing the test before starting any real work.

You may also need to consult with some kind of test-manager for your group, and seek their input to the coverage/bug rate/common problems, etc for that part of the code.

When I look at old tests in our code base, it's sometimes best to remove, sometimes worth "fixing up" and sometimes worth starting from scratch. Unless you are familiar with the test, it's hard to say before you spend some effort on investigating the issue...